# Is silicone a thermal insulator or conductor?

Tags: power, temperature, heat, materials

I'm working on a circuit which will rest on top of the lithium polymer cell that powers it. A large portion of this circuit would be better off with minimal temperature drift so I'm planning to place a thin silicone sheet between the two to solve this.

Of course air would be a better insulator (I think so at least) but the height requirements are quite stringent and this would be difficult to achieve with good mechanical stability.

I am quite confused as I see silicone used for both thermal insulation as well as conduction in different applications.

For instance, I have seen them used to connect heat sinks to ICs (see 3M thermally conductive interface pads for example.) I have also seen silicone used for insulating applications, and a quick google for "is silicone a thermal insulator" returns multiple pages stating "silicone has a low thermal conductivity."

What am I not understanding here? Is a silicone sheet a good idea to keep my circuit insulated from the battery temperature to some extent or would it achieve exactly the opposite of that? If so, what is a cheap, thin and widely available material that could achieve this function?

Comment: "Silicone" could mean a lot of different things. I think you need to be more specific.

Comment: A silicone (or similar material) can be both an electrical insulator and a thermal conductor.  For an example, look at some of the products from Aptek (not an endorsement).

Comment: Thermal pads aren’t just made of silicone - this is just a binder for a ceramic powder or whatever is used to improve the thermal conductivity. Same with thermal paste.

Comment: Same with thermal heatsink paste and conductive epoxy - very specific contaminants are introduced (to increase some property) while still retaining original function.

Comment: Sometimes if you really need it to be electrically insulating but thermally insulating such as to electrically isolate a heatsink, you use a thin material that is electrically insulating, even if it's also thermally insulating because you're making it really thin.

Comment: There are very thin sheets of pyrolytic graphite or other materials with very high in-plane thermal conductivity - up to 1kW/(m*K) - and out-of-plane thermal conductivity more than an order of magnitude lower that are designed to be used as heat spreaders in laptops and the like.  Depending on your geometry, you could place the heat spreader sheet against the battery to pull the heat somewhere else and stack an insulating material on top of that to further isolate your board.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CES Selector Version 4.7.0 lists three unfilled silicone elastomers with a thermal conductivity of range 0.38 W / m K to 2.55 W / m K. Anything below 1 W / m K is a pretty poor thermal  <s>insulator</s>  conductor.

The thermal conductivity versus cost per volume is for all the materials in the database is shown below:

[image]

If you zoom in on the lower left hand corner, it's mostly polymer foams (light green):

[image]

In general, thin things don't make great thermal insulators due to their low thermal resistance (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_resistance). You either need something thick, something with air gaps, or both.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, however I'm not sure I follow, you say that "anything below 1 W / m K is a pretty poor thermal insulator" but the materials you list are on the lower end of the chart well below that value. Did I misunderstand your answer or did you make a mistake in that sentence ?

Comment: @Ryan sorry about that. I meant anything below 1 W / m K is a pretty poor thermal conductor. Sometimes I type faster than I think :)

Answer (score 1):

If the thermal insulation requires either a layer of gas or vacuum, then a solid or liquid layer would need to be order(s) of magnitude thicker than the gas/vacuum layer to have just as low thermal conductivity.

Any polymer you put in a thin layer between the battery and the PCB will only improve thermal conductivity from battery to PCB. An uncontrolled layer of air - with occasional contact areas - will work way better than a layer of polymer that is guaranteed to be in intimate contact with both.

Your best bet for a mechanically stable insulator is a grid-shaped spacer. The area covered by the grid material must be 3+ orders of magnitude smaller than the area covered by the gas pockets between the grid lines. Then it'll act as-if the spacer wasn't there.